# Is it possible to change background color of some cells in UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

So, I have an array of levels. The number of cells depends on that array. For example, a user has completed 3-rd (or 1, 3, 4, 5 and 93) level. How can I change background for 3-rd (or 1, 3, 4, 5 and 93) cell only?

UPD: I tried to change the color of the first cell only. The color has changed, OK. But when I started scrolling through the list, the color changed not only at the first cell.

[Before Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBv4T.png)
[After Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZMP.png)

```swift
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var levelList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return levelList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.levelLabel.text = String(levelList[indexPath.item])

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You are saying `let cell =...` and a `cell` has a `backgroundColor`. You know the index path of the cell. You know what level it represents. Keep a list of completed levels. Figure out what the color should be and set it.

Comment: Can you show some example? I tried to change the color of the first cell only. The color has changed, OK. But when I started scrolling through the list, the color changed not only at the first cell.

Comment: BTW, I have attached screenshots in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, this is assuming you have a way to get the completed levels which you seem to have, and of course this is not the best implementation, since it's running the for loop each time you're scrolling through the cells, this is just to give you an idea of how you can do it.

```
var levelsCompleted = [1,2,3,93] 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.levelLabel.text = String(levelList[indexPath.item])

    for i in levelsCompleted {
        cell.backgroundColor = levelList.contains(i) ? .red : .white
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I understood. Thank you!